# US Fed Student Loan forgiven

Tags: united-states, student-loan

Are federal student loans forgiven after making payments on time for a certain number of years such as 20?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no set period after which loans are forgiven, but there are a number of forgiveness programs for federal student loan debt, the Public Service Loan Forgiveness Program can qualify you for loan forgiveness after 10 years of qualifying payments if you work in what they consider to be public service (popular among doctors who can qualify by working at a non-profit hospital).

There may be other similar programs for specific scenarios, and such programs can come and go. For everyone that doesn't qualify for a specific program like that, there are a variety of income-based repayment plans, all of which include forgiveness after 20-25 years. Under these plans, if your income is low enough you might actually make no loan payments.

Any forgiven debt will be considered income.

Here's a guide on [income-based repayment](https://studentaid.ed.gov/sa/repay-loans/understand/plans/income-driven) from the horses mouth.